# Extension of Discrete Valuation Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(R, m_R, \kappa_R) \subset (B, m_B, \kappa_B)$ be an extension of discrete valuation rings whose corresponding extension of fields of fractions $K :=\text{Frac}(R) \subset \text{Frac}(B) =: L$ is finite of degree $n:=[L:K]$.
It is well known that in general we have only the inequality $[L:K] \ge e_{B/R} \cdot [\kappa_B: \kappa_R]$, where $e_{B/R}$ is the ramification degree, i.e., minimal $e \ge 1$ with $m_B^e = m_RB$ for the maximal ideals.

**Questions:**

1. I'm looking for a reference for the proof that the equality $[L:K] = e_{B/R} \cdot [\kappa_B: \kappa_R]$ holds iff $R \to B$ is finite. For instance, it is well known that this holds for $L/K$ separable, if we localize the rings of integers at a place for number fields.
2. Secondly, I'm looking for an example of field extension generated by a single element, i.e., $L=K(\alpha)$, such that we have proper inequality $[L:K] >e_{B/R} \cdot [\kappa_B: \kappa_R]$. In light of the quoted result in first part, this is equivalent to that the extension of DVR's $R \to B$ should infinite even though $L/K$ is finite.
   Is there a "conceptional" (="by recipe")  way to construct such extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R\subset B$ is finite, then $B$ is a free module over $R$ since finitely generated torsion free module over a dvr is free. The rest is easy.

For the second, take $R=\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x)}$ and $L=K(y)$ with $y^2=x+1$. Then $B= R[y]_{(y-1)}$ is a dvr with the properties you want.

Comment: Concerning the first problem, right, then $B \cong R^n$ as $R$-module with $n= [L:K]$ because $B \otimes_R K=L$ using flatness and that for any $a \in L$ there exist a $r \in R$ with $ar \in B$, and since $m_B /m_B^2 \cong m_B^r/m_B^{r+1}$ we obtain $n = e_{B/R} \cdot [\kappa_B: \kappa_R]$ by tensoring $B$ with $\kappa_R$. What about the other direction?

Comment: But I'm not sure why your suggested counterexample concerning question 2 should work. $K:=\text{Frac}(R)$ in your example is a field of characteristic $0$, so any finite extension of $K$ is automatically separable, so $R \subset B$ is finite, see eg Liu's AG 4.1.25. Correct me, if my reasonings are wrong.

Comment: @user267839 No, the integral closure of $R$ in $K$ is finite. But $B$ is a localization and not finite.

Comment: That appears a bit creepy as I agree that $B$ is not finite over $R$, as for every $r>1$ the element $\frac{1}{(y-1)^r}$ cannot be generated inside of the $R$-module generated by  $\frac{1}{(y-1)},  \frac{1}{(y-1)^2}...,  \frac{1}{(y-1)^{r-1}}$, but on the other hand the proposition 4.1.25 I quoted from Liu's book states that for a normal, Noetherian scheme $X$ and finite separable extension $L/K(X)$ the normalization $X_L \to X$ with respect $L$ is finite. If we take $X:=\text{Spec}(R)$ and $L=\text{Frac}(B)$ the quoted proposition can be applied if I'm not missing something. That's strange

Comment: as I can't find a problem with your counterexample, which seemingly contradict this proposition. Do you see where I making an error in my reasonings?

Comment: @user267839 As I said Liu is correct, but $B$, as I said is NOT the normalization, but a further localization.

Comment: @Alright I see, then I guess in your penultimate sentence you meant "intergral closure of $R$ in $L$ is finite" (not $K$, even though it's clearly also true just from trivial reasons)

Comment: Do you maybe know a counterexample in the same setting as above but where we **assume** that $B$ in the question is the normalization of $R$ with respect a finite (... and neccessarity not separable) exitension $L/K$? Can it also constructed if we additionally assume that $L$ is generated over $K$ by a single element? (morally,  an example, where 4.1.25 cannot be applied, due to missing separability, and where the normalization itself turns out to be infinite)